# Copy extracted files from ZIP to directory

Tags: php, copy

Note: I'm on localhost, so CHMOD'ing is not the answer.

---

Anyway, I can't get to copy the files which were extracted from a ZIP to a directory, the files are extracted, but they won't be copied... the files just lay in the root folder where `upload.php` is. I've got this:

```
exec('unzip ' . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $ary, $output);

$img = 0;

$number = count($ary);

foreach($ary as $file)
{
    copy($file, 'i/');
    unlink($file);
    $img++;
}

echo $img . '/' . $number;
```

It outputs 11/11, so thats good... but the files are not copied and the original files are not deleted. Why isn't it copying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming the array `$ary` has the filenames in them. But it does not.

`$ary` which hold the output of the `unzip` command will be something like:

```
extracting: foo
extracting: bar
...
```

Try dumping the array contents using `var_dump($ary)` to confirm this.

My advice would be don't use external `unzip` command, instead use [build in zip functions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) as:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open("$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']") === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('i/');
    $zip->close();
} else {
    // failed to extract.
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer, although probably should note that ZipArchive was added in a later revision of PHP 4. If you're on an old system you may be forced to just parse the output of a shell exec() line.

Answer (score 0):

As codaddict already mentioned, try PECL zip module, or PEAR File_Archive.
But if you can't install any of those, and stuck with an old PHP, try:

```
exec('unzip ' . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] . ' | tail -n"+2" | cut -d" " -f4 ', $ary, $output);
```

That should give you just the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

It does not copy the files beause you did not read the manual fully:

*$dest - The destination path. If $dest is a URL, the copy operation may fail if the wrapper does not support overwriting of existing files.
Warning: If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.*

You need to specify the full destination path (including filename), not only the directory.